# Cross-browser dropshadows on boxes

Tags: html, image, css

I am building a new site which has drop shadows on various page elements (boxes, inputs etc). The site as a whole needs to be the same across all browsers (back to IE7).

My issue lies with the best way to implement these drop shadows on many different elements on new and old browsers.

[image]

I am aware of the css3 solution with no images: `box-shadow: 1px 1px #333` - but this won't degrade well.

I don't really want to use images for every element as we would be looking at 4 images per element and requests to the server and page load time would get ridiculous just for a simple effect.

Is it possible to even create a fallback say: *If the browser doesn't support box-shadow, use images*? Only issue I see with this is lots of extra mark up which can make it harder to manage.

I guess the difficulty here is the requirement "I want it modern but to degrade nicely".
**What solution is best for me when implementing drop shadows (is there an alternative) ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use http://modernizr.com to detect if the current user using browser with css3 support but I think you better use the old way to make a box with drop shadow.

You can make it with the "Sliding doors" technique for the top and bottom of the box and use another background image for the box itself.

Anyway you can use CSS3 pie ( http://css3pie.com/) but I usually don't like this plugin because it's a little buggy sometimes and raise the browser performance needed.

Comment: css3pie looks good, I didn't realise there was a `.htc` file for this. Does it *"raise the browser performance needed."* for all browsers or just IE?

Comment: I read on their documentation: `the .htc file loads asynchronously.` and `the .htc behavior applies itself while the page is still loading.`. This sounds great, but do you know if it makes a noticeable difference?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use css

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(...);
```

but this shadows are terrible. I think the best solution is to show shadows only in modern browsers, which allow box-shadow.

Comment: I agree, I'd love to say "for any old browser, dont worry about the drop shadow". Unfortunately I need some ammunition as to why, and to understand all my options instead of saying "just because".

Comment: Unfortunately I am a developer, the requirement comes from a client and I cannot simply send them that link (as much as I would love to). The response I expect from them in regards to that link is "**Why?**

Comment: Fortunately, as a developer, you have the knowledge and expertise that your clients want (and are, presumably, paying for). This includes the ability to say things like "Old browsers won't render fancy cool effects like drop shadows. It's going to *look better* if we don't use their terrible implementation."

Comment: Yes, I agree. I just don't know much about the alternative solutions for box-shadows except the old school stuff. I want to be able to say *other implementations are terrible* with the knowledge they are instead of just assuming.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can check it with Javascript

```
var supports = (function() {  
   var div = document.createElement('div'),  
      vendors = 'Khtml Ms O Moz Webkit'.split(' '),  
      len = vendors.length;  
   return function(prop) {  
      if ( prop in div.style ) return true;  
      prop = prop.replace(/^[a-z]/, function(val) {  
         return val.toUpperCase();  
      });  
      while(len--) {  
         if ( vendors[len] + prop in div.style ) {  
            // browser supports box-shadow. Do what you need.  
            // Or use a bang (!) to test if the browser doesn't.  
            return true;  
         }  
      }  
      return false;  
   };  
})();  
if ( supports('textShadow') ) { 
   document.documentElement.className += ' textShadow';  
}
```

And then put in the else statement that you want to use images or You can use an library called Modernizer http://www.modernizr.com/ so older browser know how they have to implement css3 tags

Link to source for the code: [SOURCECODE](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-detect-css-support-in-browsers-with-javascript/)

Comment: +1 for modernizr. I have looked at it briefly before. Definitely a solution if I was worried about more cross-browser issues other than just box-shadows. That code you posted is useful too, but what alternative would you recommend?

Comment: You can use images or you can use the code from ManseUk like this `.shadow {

 -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;

 -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;

 box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;

 /* For IE 8 */

 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000')";

 /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */

 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000');
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following for older versions of IE :

```
/* For IE 8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000')";
/* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000');
```

[MSDN Details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533086%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Example here](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/filter/Shadow.htm)